# how to pass array of pointer of pointers to a function?

Tags: c

I know how to modify an array of pointers in main, but don't know how to do it when my function need to modify it.
The code between ** is how I do it in main without using a function. I know how to print the array of pointer of pointer out. My question is, suppose I want to move these lines ** into function(), what do I need to modify?

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void function(char *array[], int size);
void function_print(char *array[], int size);
int main()
{
    char *array[] = {0};

    char word[20];

    **scanf("%s", word);
    int len = strlen(word) + 1;
    array[size] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(len));          
    strlcpy(array[size], word, sizeof(array[size]));**


    function(array, 0);

    return 0;
}

void function(char *array[], int size)
{

}

void function_print(char *array[], int size)
{
   for(int x = 0; x < size; x ++)
   {
       printf("%s", *array);
       (array)++;
   }
}


~
~
```

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense *prior* to your function call.  It doesn't look like you even need an array of pointers to do what you might be trying to do.  Moreover, both places you're using `sizeof()` look problematic and probably aren't doing what you're intending.  You might get better answers by clarifying what you're intending to do.

Answer (score 1):

I made some edit and realized your function will do the same. So go on, and read the **EDIT** if you don't know how it works.

Besides I think there's something wrong in your main(). First, array[size] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(len)); tends to report an error because no size is defined here. Second, if by size you mean the number of elements in array, then array[size] would cause an overflow. Third, the argument of malloc should be sizeof(char)*len, not sizeof(len), since the latter equals sizeof(int).

Change your function to

```
void function(char **, int);
```

And call it by

```
function(array, 0);
```

**EDIT**

I think by "modify it" you mean to change the pointers stored in the array. Since every element is a `char*`, a `char**` will do the job.

When you pass `array` as an argument, actually you're passing the **address** of the first element. Then in the function you receive it with a `char** parray`. Since you have also passed the size, you can use it as a `char* parray[]`, and the address of every element is exactly the same with `array` in `main()`. Thus, any modification you do with `parray` will change `array`. Is that what you want?

Comment: There is no difference between `void function(char *array[], int size);` and `void function(char **, int);`.

Comment: isn't this `function` practically the same as what he had?

Comment: your answer only let me print my array of pointers, what if I need to initialize my array of pointers of pointers?

Comment: @user1701840 The memory space of an array is allocated automatically on the stack, so you won't have to "initialize" the whole array, only each element. And as I said, any modification to any element of `parray` will happen to `array`, since they share the same address. It doesn't only allow you to print, but to do any change. Have a try, for every `parray[i]` use `parray[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20)` and `strcpy` a string into it, then print  it in `main()`. You'll see the modification does take place.

Comment: @user1701840 Besides I think there's something wrong in your `main()`. First, `array[size] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(len));` tends to report an error because no `size` is defined here. Second, if by `size` you mean the number of elements in `array`, then `array[size]` would cause an overflow. Third, the argument of `malloc` should be `sizeof(char)*len`, not `sizeof(len)`, since the latter equals `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: hm, this post isn't that clear. please refer to this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606914/how-to-pass-an-array-of-pointer-to-pointer-to-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You are doing no mistake in calling the function and passing the array of char pointers. This is a right way. Your program did not compile for me, so made some small changes. It works.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<iostream>

    void function(char *array[], int size);
    int main()
    {
        char *array[] = {0};
        char word[20];
        scanf("%s", word);
        int len = strlen(word) + 1;
        array[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(len));          //that how I do it in main without using a function.
        strcpy(array[0], word);


        function(array, 0);

        return 0;
    }

    void function(char *array[], int size)
    {
        char * temp =  new char[strlen(array[0])+1];
        strcpy(temp, array[0]);
        printf(temp, 's');

    }
```

Comment: Ohh! That's silly. Just look into the section that passes the array which is the point in question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this :

`void function(char *array[], int size)`

and this:

`void function(char **array, int size)`

are same in this context.

If you define a function like this then its not necessary to declare it like the same , you can declare it like :
`void function(char **, int );`

declaration only describes the return type and arguments' type of a function.Now, some other recommendations:

**Do not use** `scanf` like this :

`scanf("%s", word);// you need to specify field width in case of strings otherwise it will overwrite buffer in case of large strings` therefore, do it like this :

`scanf("%19s",word);`

`size` is not defined in your main, instead I would rather prefer to do this way :

```
size_t len = sizeof(word) + 1;// yes, try to use size_t when returning number of bytes 
    *array = (char*)malloc(sizeof len);// casting malloc is not recommended though. 
    strncpy(*array, word,len);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try doing :

```
void function(char *array, int size)();
```

And instead of:

```
function(array,0);
```

because array itself it is a memroy address.