# undesired output from my function that using malloc

Tags: c

I tried input "aaaaaaa", and "bbbb". And I got my print function output something like "aaabb". It seems like I had a bad management of memory here,  but I couldn't find the place. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  

void function(char *array[], int size);
void function2(char *array[], int size);

int main()
{
    int size = 0;  
    char *array[] = {0};  
    function(array, 0);  
    size++;  
    function(array, 1);  
    size++;  
    function2(array,2);  
    return 0; 
}

void function(char *array[], int size)
{
    char word[20] = "0";
    scanf("%s", word);
    int len = strlen(word) + 1;
    array[size] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(len));
    strlcpy(array[size], word, sizeof(len));
}

void function2(char *array[], int size)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x ++)
    {
        printf("%s", *array);
        (array)++;
    }
}
```

~

Comment: You never allocate any space for the variable `array`.

Comment: @John3136 Then what `char *array[] = {0};` is? The problem is different, see the posted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/17606293 or exact duplicate with title changed to mislead. And one more :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606914/how-to-pass-an-array-of-pointer-to-pointer-to-a-function-in-c .... how can the same code be posted from different guys?

Comment: @PHIfounder: Seems like He posted it once, then again reposted it after editing it, and another guy then posted the same with a different title. Why is the question so popular? Or is the entire team/class copied the same code and everybody got the bug :P

Answer (score 2):

You original array has a size of one

`char *array[] = {0};` is equal to `char *array[1] = {0};`

Then later you try to write into unreserved space `array[size]` where size is more than 0.

Declare array as:

```
char *array[ 3 ] ;
```

Calling `sizeof` on the variable `len`, gives you the size of the variable itself, *not* the value it is holding.

Comment: tried, similar result :(